# MPI - C - sending array acting wierd

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

This is small piece of larger code using MPI in C. I can't figure out why the output is like this.
Code:

```
int *work=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
work = get_borders(32);

/* Send it to each rank */
printf("Master sending\n w1 %d w2  %d to slave %d\n",work[0],work[1],rank);
fflush(stdout);
MPI_Send(&work,             /* message buffer */
         2,                 /* one data item */
         MPI_INT,           /* data item is an integer */
         rank,              /* destination process rank */
         10,           /* user chosen message tag */
         MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Check back values...\n w1 %d w2  %d for slave %d\n",work[0],work[1],rank);
fflush(stdout);
```

Output for code above:

```
Master sending  w1 0 w2  32 to slave 1 Check back values...  w1
2293552 w2  28079928 for slave 1
```

The problem is that values 0 and 32 are correct but I can't understand why there are those long numbers. The worst thing is that those random numbers are received on the other side in Recv function. I don't understand this at all — can you explain?

Recv Code Added

```
`while (1) {
   int  wor[2];
    /* Receive a message from the master */

   MPI_Recv (wor, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  printf("Slave %d recieving from master w1 %d w2 %d\n",rank,wor[0],wor[1]);`
```

Comment: can you show your receive code as well?

Comment: Here it is `while (1) {
   int  wor[2];
    /* Receive a message from the master */

   MPI_Recv (wor, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  printf("Slave %d recieving from master w1 %d w2 %d\n",rank,wor[0],wor[1]);`

Comment: Please add your receive code to the question so that it is formatted readably.  Please note that I just cleaned up your question a little, too.

Comment: Are you sure you want `&work` rather than just `work` as the parameter to `MPI_Send()`?

Comment: well to be honest i was so desperate ive tried all the combinations with and without & .So that didnt help .But yes im aware that it should be only work

Comment: Are you sure you want to send from EVERY `rank`? and receive from every `rank`?

Comment: i dont quiet understand you. I send messages to every rank except me (the master) and all ranks are recieving messages only from master.Maybe i should mention that send code is wrapped in for loop that runs from 1 to number of ranks

Comment: The problem is somwhere else i think because when i send single integer it works perfectly fine and correct number is recieved

Comment: Is your problem that you are defining the data type  `MPI_INT`? When it should be `MPI_DOUBLE`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV` calls you are defining the data type as `MPI_INT` which explains why it works as an integer. You need to change this to `MPI_DOUBLE` for it to work with a double

Answer (score 0):

Usually this shows a data type problem
the data you're sending is more than 32 bits which starts to show incorrect data ( such as 2293552 and 28079928 )
In order to avoid such problems, use double datatype instead
i use double in mpi usually to avoid datatype problems